# Adding strings together in easy and less code way

Tags: c++, string

I tried to add multiple strings together and store in a Full string variable like this:

```
string s_fullPath = string1 + string2 + string3 + string3 +
        string4 + string5 + string6 + string7, ..;
```

Is there any easier and less code way to do this? This way makes code interface messy and ugly. (My thinking)

Comment: Don't use +, use +=.  Otherwise many temporary strings created.  Also, it may be clearer.

Comment: string1 and others are predefined variables not just in line.

Comment: Lets flip this around.  Do you really need more than 3-4 string it express a full path?  Why do you have so many strings that need to concatenated together?

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin My comment still holds.  string1 + string2 produces a temporary.

Comment: Can't you store `string1` - `stringN` in a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of individual variables, and use a loop to concatenate them all?

Comment: Please give us an example of the values of string 1 ... string n.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I need more than 3-4 strings, because of function input parameters.

Comment: @AnonMail On the other hand += will modify strings you may not wish to modify.

Comment: @DaveS Those are just like this: string1 = "123456", string2 = "message" and more.

Comment: @user4581301 In the above example, only one string is being modified.

Comment: @AnonMail Are you suggesting `string s_fullPath += string1 + string2 + string3 ...` or `string s_fullPath += string1 += string2 += string3 ...`

Comment: You could use a `std::stringstream`. Lower potential for temporary bufferage (Though to be honest the compiler can probably eliminate that) but I don't think this gives you anything easier to write or easier to read than what you have with +.

Comment: @NathanOliver - neither.  See my answer below.

Comment: @user0042 I did this, But I get the error: **no instance of constructor matches the argument list**.

Comment: The problem with the `vector` and loop approach is unless the vector comes pre-loaded, loading the `vector` is going to have you writing at least as much code.

Comment: My opinion, and this is opinion, is you aren't going to do much better without sacrificing readability, and I think it questionable that you can do that much better even with unreadable code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead of [`operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << string1
    << string2
    << string3
    << string3
    << string4
    << string5
    << string6
    << string7
    << ...;
string s_fullPath = oss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
    string s_fullPath = string1;
           s_fullPath += string2;
            ...
```

It's clearer and you don't produce all the temporary strings.

Comment: Please could you provide the reference to this assertion

Comment: [`operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) creates a temporary. Every call to `operator+` in the OP's example creates a new temporary, concatenating them together. By the time `;` is reached, there are 7+ temporaries in memory (a temporary is not freed until the end of the entire expression is reached).  Using [`std::string::operator+=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) instead avoids any need for creating temporaries.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes. You beat me to it.